# How long do Drupal caches last?

Tags: performance, drupal, drupal-cache

Using the devel module I can see a lot of calls to cache_get() and cache_set(). After how long does a cached value need to be refreshed? Does the cache get invalidated every few minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module that is using [cache_set](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_set/6) sets the expiration in the call.  Some things have explicit durations, others have permanent or semi-permanent lifetimes, based on the situation.

Caches get explicitly cleared when you invoke the method through the admin interface (or drush), or otherwise through the use of [drupal_flush_all_caches](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/6) or [cache_clear_all](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/6).

Lately, I have been using a hook_cron to clear certain cache tables each night.

EDIT to answer comment:

To see which cache, I usually put this in a separate script somewhere:

```
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
header("Content-Type: text/plain; encoding=utf-8");
$user = user_load(1);
print "Modules implementing hook_cron:\n" . implode("\n", module_implements('cron'));
```

To see expirations, examine the various `cache` tables in the database and look at the `expire` column.  Modules can set expirations on each individual call to `cache_set`, so it can vary entry by entry.

Comment: Is there a way to see which modules cache and for how long?